# Populating 2 form fields based on SELETLIST selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, cfc

This is driving me crazy. I have a form with 2 fields.

```
<select name="serviceDescription" id="serviceDescription" onchange="PopulateDescriptionsField();"/> </select>
```

I populate the selectList from a CFC call via JQuery. That part works. I have a second field:

```
<input name="descriptionEdit" id="descriptionEdit" size="50">
```

I would like to set the value of descriptionEdit to the whatever value is selected in the serviceDescription selectlist.

I cant seem to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Jquery is:

```
$('body').on('click','#serviceDescription',function() {
    var value = $('#serviceDescription').val();
    $('#descriptionEdit').attr('value',value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look in to below code to edit selected option in the serviceDescription list and it may help you to implement the same.

```js
$('#serviceDescription').change(function(){
  var optValue =  $(':selected',this).text();
  $('#descriptionEdit').val(optValue);
  
  $("#descriptionEdit").keyup(function() {
    var value = $( this ).val();
    var newOptval = $( "#descriptionEdit" ).text( value );
    $(':selected','#serviceDescription').text(value).val(value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="serviceDescription" id="serviceDescription">
  <option value='service1'>service1</option>
  <option value='service2'>service2</option>
  <option value='service3'>service3</option>
  <option value='service4'>service4</option>
  <option value='service5'>service5</option>
  <option value='service6'>service6</option>
  <option value='service7'>service7</option>
  <option value='service8'>service8</option>
</select>
<input name="descriptionEdit" id="descriptionEdit" size="50">
```